# Where can I download libc++_shared.so for Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

My Android missing the C++ library so when I download it for 64bits I will need to push it to my Android using adb. I also don't know where it normally sit to push it to the exact location.

Comment: The library should be packed automatically. What error message do you get and what depends on this .so?

Answer (score 0):

1. If the App needs the lib .so to compile the app with native cpp code, NDK would have the ANDROID_STL dependent libs to configure to build the app. build.gradle file config properties can be used to solve the NDK build errors. The same c++11 stl can be added also in `CMakeLists.txt` as well.

   ```
    externalNativeBuild {
          cmake {  
            cppFlags "-std=c++11 -fexceptions -frtti"
            arguments "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared"
        }
    }
   ```

The APK can be generated after the build issues resolved and the same can be analysed the cross check on native libs when there is a Linking error occurs.

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed

2. No need to push these C++ libs as it's part of the Android system standard native libs. If there is a need to push then it should be into `system/lib` with special permissions.

Android system would lookup for the .so libs as per it's arch layers defined when the app is loading at runtime. for ex. `/data/app-lib/packagename/`, `/system/lib`, `/vendor/lib`.

If there is a need of pushing these libs then the device should be rooted. Should follow the below steps to push

a. `adb root`
b. `adb remount`
c. `adb push <source_path> <destination_path>`